# ClickListener never deallocated?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I've got a `Fragment` and add a `ClickListener` to a button:

```
$.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new ViewOnClickListenerOnAddButtonClicked());
```

According to the `MemoryAnalyzer`, it never gets deallocated; when I'm navigating to and from the according `Fragment`, it appears as if the `Fragment` itself exists only once, but the amount of `OnClickListener`s adds up.

For testing I added a completely empty one:

```
private static class ViewOnClickListenerOnAddButtonClicked implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

(the name is also only that I'm finding it in `MemoryAnalyzer`)

Here's the output from `MemoryAnalyzer`:

[image]

The first is the `Fragment` itself which a count of 1, but the `ViewOnClickListenerOnAddButtonClicked` seems to exist 4 times now (once for every time I navigated to it).

What could be the reason for this when there's an empty `OnClickListener`?

Comment: Have you manually called GC with both classes? The anonymous inner class holds a reference to the Fragment, which could cause a leak.

Comment: I didn't call GC manually; but there is no anonymous inner class

Comment: My bad, I thought the first statement was a different class from the second statement.